# linking input fields together using listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind several input fields to a span element using jQuery. As an example, I have 2 input fields with integer values. The sum of the integer values is shown in a span element. Now the span element should always update when one of the input fields is modified (for this is use .keyup() event in jquery). I have a working solution. But it seems to me a limping solution. So I wonder how you would it. Thank you in advance.

here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/SJAwb/2/

Cheers
Wolfgang

Comment: Try http://knockoutjs.com, which has [`ko.observable()`](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) (also see this page of [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)).

Comment: this should probably go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you Jared very helpful js framework tip. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you just can't do :

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) e.preventDefault();
    var span = $(this).nextAll('span').first(),
        val = this.value,
        mult = $('#'+span.data("multiplier")).val();
    span.html(( parseFloat(val, 10) * parseFloat(mult, 10) ));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SJAwb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use class selector instead of ID selector.

Add all input box value and multiply with the multiplier value.. the div in the demo is just for show and doesn't really needed.

See my approach below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SJAwb/8/

**JS:**

```
$('.listener').each(function () {
    var element = $(this),
        dataBound = $(this).data('bound'),
        dataMultiplier = $(this).data("multiplier"),
        val;

    $('.' + dataBound).on('keyup', {db: dataBound, dm: dataMultiplier}, function (event) {
        /* block ENTER key stroke */
        if (event.which === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        /* calculate result */
        val = 0;

        $('.' + event.data.db).each(function (idx, el) {
            val += parseFloat (el.value, 10);
        });

        val = val * parseFloat($('.' + event.data.dm).val());

        if (isNaN(val)) {
          element.html("Please enter a valid number");
        } else {
          element.html(val);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: also very helpful und kind of what I was looking for. thank you